# Can't install cygnus-ngsi via Docker

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am trying to install cygnus-ngsi, following [this](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_docker/index.html) guide. While installing via Docker, I get the following error:

```
INFO: Apache domain <http://apache.rediris.es/>
INFO: URL MAVEN <http://apache.rediris.es/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: URL FLUME <http://apache.rediris.es/flume/1.4.0/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: Download and install Maven and Flume...
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

It seems to be that the mirror http://apache.rediris.es is down. Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mirror seems to be up and running now. For the future, we'll try to work on a solution that tries several mirrors, or the main one (despite the downloading speed could be slower).

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by modifying `fiware-cygnus/docker/cygnus-ngsi/Dockerfile`, replacing the assignment below:

```
APACHE_DOMAIN="$(curl -s 'https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?as_json=1' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj["preferred"]')" \
      || APACHE_DOMAIN="http://archive.apache.org/dist/" && \
```

with this:

```
APACHE_DOMAIN="http://archive.apache.org/dist/" && \
```

This modification ensures that [Apache Archive](http://archive.apache.org) is used for downloading both FLUME and MAVEN binaries and results in a successful build.