# Repo errors installing Cygnus via Docker

Tags: fiware-cygnus

Based on previous post, I believe Cygnus docker repo is experiencing a repository problem ([Can't install cygnus-ngsi via Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216757/cant-install-cygnus-ngsi-via-docker/41686150)). I have tried some suggestion but couldn't solve it, without success.

Any suggestion to work this out?

```
---> Running in 01f1ccf107fa
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Setting up Install Process
http://centos.blazar.mx/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://centos.blazar.mx/6.8/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transfered the last 30 seconds')
Trying other mirror.
.
.
.
INFO: Java version <1.7.0>

INFO: Apache domain <http://archive.apache.org/dist/>
INFO: URL MAVEN <http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: URL FLUME <http://archive.apache.org/dist/flume/1.4.0/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin.tar.gz>
INFO: Download and install Maven and Flume...
```

Comment: This was discussed privately by email: the releasing team is studying this error. Nevertheless, the problem seems to be related with the default mirror used by `yum` when downloading some required package from México... Hard to repreduce outside México :)

Comment: hopefully this could be fixed soon because, in fact, I'm struggling with this installation hosted into FIWARE Mexico, which means, that this could be replicate within all VM from folks trying to follow respective installation option. Please, let me know if you happen to need any access to my public VM for testing or analysing this issue on deeper

Comment: In the meantime, there are more options for installing Cygnus: try the [FIWARE repo](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_with_rpm/index.html) for yum; or try [compiling Cygnus](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/install_from_sources/index.html) by yourself (not really hard).

Comment: yep, already installed for yum. Just wanted to know what was happening for future reference; though :-)

Answer (score 0):

The yum repositories has controlled by the operating system.
If exist network problems between SO and mirror repositories, or maintenance task in the yum repositories, the yum utility can be failed.
We have sometimes experienced this kind of failure, included using Centos 7.
When yum repo maintenance is being performed there's no much to do.
Within a company you can use a cache proxy.

If exists network problems, you can review host SO configuration and docker configuration. And test other fiware docker images.
Anyway, to allow us to test with a more accurate configuration, can you provide us what operating system you have, and docker version installed (rpm -qa | grep docker)?

Comment: I'm using a Centos 7 virtual machina (from FIWARE Cloud) in which I have installed a Cygnus container. Docker details are: docker-engine-selinux-1.13.0-1.el7.centos.noarch, docker-engine-1.13.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64